# pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to ***.***.*.*:5672 failed: timeout

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to one of my development server via rabbitmq.
I am able to connect to all other servers except one.
I am able to connect this server to itself.

I have tried almost all the solutions in stackoverflow.

```
connection=pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(credentials=credentials,host="**.***.*.*",socket_timeout=300))

pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:Connection to **.***.*.*:5672 failed: timeout
```

Comment: Are you sure RabbitMQ is running on that server?

Comment: The RabbitMQ team has an *extensive* guide to troubleshooting issues like this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first check wheather rabbitmq is running

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server status
```

then check if you are able to ping the server

run `ping 12.123.1.1`
now we have to check if port is open or not

```
telnet 12.123.1.1 5672
```